# Getting a list of pixels coordinates from a circular or oddly shape blob - Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I am new to image processing and I am trying to obtain a list of pixel coordinates that are found within a circular/oval/oddly shape blob.

The only way that I can think of doing it is using a bounding box but unfortunately the bounding box does go over the area.

Anyone has a better idea?

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to obtain the pixel coordinates.  Assuming your image is **binary** and stored in `im`, do:

```
[r,c] = find(im);
```

`r` and `c` will be the rows and columns of every pixel that is white.  This assumes that the object is fully closed - one caveat I'd like to mention.  If there are holes in the interior of the object, consider using [`imfill`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html) to fill in these holes, then combine it with `find`:

```
bw = imfill(im, 'holes');
[r,c] = find(bw);
```

---

If you have more than one object, use [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) and specify the `PixelList` attribute:

```
s = regionprops(im, 'PixelList');
```

This will return a `N` element structure where each structure contains a `PixelList` field that contains the `(x,y)` coordinates of each unique object.  In your case, this will be a `M x 2` matrix where the first column are the `x` or column coordinates and the second column are the `y` or row coordinates.

To access an object's pixel coordinate list, simply do:

```
coords = s(idx).PixelList;
```

`idx` is the object you want to access.

Comment: Thank you it does work! However, my image has several blobs and I would like to distinguish coordinates from one blob from another.. What would you suggest? I have uploaded the picture of how it looks like

Comment: @AliP - Use `regionprops` for that.  I'll update my post.